# Import all tables from a specific schema in an Exasol DB to Hive using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, exasolution

I´m trying to import all tables from a specific schema of an Exasol DB to Hive like this:

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect 'jdbc:exa:<ip:port>;schema=<schema_2>' \
--driver com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver --username user --password pw -m 1 \
--hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-database <schema_2> --as-parquetfile
```

But i get this error:

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: object AA__PERF_LOG not found [line 1, column 17] (Session: 1585933664557550733)
java.sql.SQLException: object AA__PERF_LOG not found [line 1, column 17] (Session: 1585933664557550733)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.ExceptionFactory.createSQLException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.ExceptionFactory.createSQLException(ExceptionFactory.java:21)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.AbstractEXAPreparedStatement.<init>(AbstractEXAPreparedStatement.java:67)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.AbstractEXAPreparedStatement_14.<init>(AbstractEXAPreparedStatement_14.java:14)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.EXAPreparedStatement.<init>(EXAPreparedStatement.java:13)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.DialectGeneric.createPreparedStatement(DialectGeneric.java:10)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.AbstractEXAConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractEXAConnection.java:880)
        at com.exasol.jdbc.AbstractEXAConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractEXAConnection.java:915)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:328)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1853)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1653)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:488)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportAllTablesTool.run(ImportAllTablesTool.java:111)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
```

It seems sqoop trys to import the table AA_PERF_LOG, which is the first Table of the complete database, but not part of the specified Schema.

- Exasol

  - schema_1
         - AA_PERF_LOG
  - schema_2

I already tried to specify the schema with

```
-- --schema
```

But this just causes the exact same error.

Comment: Ist seems --Schema ist not supported in the import-all-tabels tool [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/88072/sqoop-import-all-tables.html). But this post is allready half a year old, therefore i don´t know if it´s still up to date. If it is, is there any other simple way to Import all tables from a database Schema?